# showing that a sequence is converging.

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

suppose $\left \{ T_{k} \right \}$ is a collection of bounded operators on Hilbert space $H$ ,with $\left \| T_{k} \right \|\leq 1$ for all $k$ .suppose also that $$T_{k}T_{j}^{*}=T_{k}^{*}T_{j}=0    $$ for all $k\neq j$ .let $S_{N}=\sum _{k=-N}^{N}T_{k}$ .show that $S_{N}(f)$ converges as $N\rightarrow \infty $,for every $f\in H $ .if $T(f)$ denotes the limit ,prove that $\left \| T \right \|\leq 1$.

this is  exercise 23,page 198 of real analysis of estein.
I thought that this is a good idea to show the sequence is cauchy,but I don't know what I must do next.I need help.

Comment: Looking at the answer below, did you mean to say $T_kT_j^*=T_k^*T_j = 0$ for $j \ne k$?  Otherwise just let $T_k = I$ for all $k$, and then it is clear that the conclusion is false.

Comment: yes you are right,I mean that they are equal to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You can consider how to do each of the following four steps:

**Step 1:** Show that the range of $T_j$ and the range of $T_k$ (reps. the ranges of $T_j^*$ and of $T_k^*$) are orthogonal if $j\ne k$.

**Step 2:** Let $E_k$ be the closure of the range of $T_k^*$, and let $F$ be the closure of the subspace spanned by all the $E_k$. Show that if $j\ne k$, then
$$T_jf=0$$
for all $f\in E_k+F^\perp$. Deduce that $T_j=T_j\circ P_j$, where $P_j$ is the orthogonal projection onto $E_j$.

**Step 3:** Assume that there exists $N_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $T_k=0$ for all $N\ge N_0$. Show that $S_{N_0}$ is a linear and bounded operator on $\mathcal{H}$, with its norm less than $1$. (the core is to use the fact that $T_kf=T_k(P_kf)$ and $\|T_kf\|$ is bounded by $\|P_kf\|$. Use this to show that $\{S_n(f)\}$ is Cauchy.)

**Step 4:** Extend your method in **step 3** to the case in which there are infinitely many non-zero $T_k$. Conclude.